# How do i access the values in this date (object?)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile

in the following code, how can I access the date and time?

I also tried using the functions in the Text block to no avail. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and how to access this object, or how to make it into an object that is accessible from elsewhere.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Button, Platform} from 'react-native';
import DateTimePicker from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker';

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    date: new Date('2020-06-12T14:42:42'),
    mode: 'date',
    show: false,
  }

  setDate = (event, date) => {
    date = date || this.state.date;

    this.setState({
      show: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? true : false,
      date,
    });
  }

  show = mode => {
    this.setState({
      show: true,
      mode,
    });
  }

  datepicker = () => {
    this.show('date');
  }

  timepicker = () => {
    this.show('time');
  }

  render() {
    const { show, date, mode } = this.state;

    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          <Button onPress={this.datepicker} title="Show date picker!" />
        </View>
        <View>
          <Button onPress={this.timepicker} title="Show time picker!" />
        </View>
        { show && <DateTimePicker value={date}
                    mode={mode}
                    is24Hour={true}
                    display="default"
                    onChange={this.setDate} />
        }
      </View>
    );
```

I've tried many variations of

`<Text style={styles.pickedDate}>{date.getDate()}</Text>`

also using state and this instead of date.

Comment: What is the output of ```date.getDate()``` ?

Comment: Can you explain more precisly what the problem is ? What do you expect and what do you actually get ?

Comment: @MichaelBahl the output was the correct output, I just had the views wrong. Thank you for the reply though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to display the date from the state in the same component you will need to access it like:

```
<Text style={styles.pickedDate}>{this.state.date.toString()}</Text>
```

You may use `{this.state.date.getDate()}` but it will only get you the day of the month, 12 in your example.